# call an ember component action from within the component

Tags: ember.js

I am creating a component to wrap the select2 select box. The code is below:

```
App.FixedSelectComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    change: function(value) {
      this.set('selectedValue',value);
    }
  },

didInsertElement : function(){
  this.$("#select1").select2().on("change", function(e) {
      if ($.isArray(e.val)) {
          $.each(e.val, function(index,value) {
              console.log("multiple:",value.split('>')[2].split('<')[0]);
             // send to change
          });             
      } else {
          console.log("single:",e.val.split('>')[2].split('<')[0]);  
          // send to change
      }
    });
  },

  willDestroyElement : function() {
    this.$("#select1").select2('destroy');
},

});
```

however, what I am stuck at is how to send the data that I've got in the on("change") event to the action:change that I've defined , or if I can set the selectedValue property itself in the on("change") event

"this" isn't the component at the "// send to change" lines - how / where do I get the reference to the component itself at this point ?

basically what I am trying to achieve is to get the data passed to the "change" event of select2 into my selectedValue property

thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Component.send('actionName')`.

I found it in [Ember's documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_send).

Answer (score 2):

`this` context will not refer to FixedSelectComponent context in `$.each`, and also use send method which will call FixedSelectComponent change method..

refer : http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_send

```
didInsertElement : function(){
  var _this = this;
  this.$("#select1").select2().on("change", function(e) {
      if ($.isArray(e.val)) {
          $.each(e.val, function(index,value) {
              console.log("multiple:",value.split('>')[2].split('<')[0]);
             _this.send('change',value.split('>')[2].split('<')[0]); // send to change
          });             
      } else {
          console.log("single:",e.val.split('>')[2].split('<')[0]);  
          _this.send('change',e.val.split('>')[2].split('<')[0]); // send to change
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.get('actions').change.call(this, value);
```

Check http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_actions -- `'actions'` is simply another property on your Component.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
App.FixedSelectComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  change: function(value) {
    this.set('selectedValue',value);
  }

  didInsertElement : function(){
    var self = this;
    this.$("#select1").select2().on("change", function(e) {
      if ($.isArray(e.val)) {
         $.each(e.val, function(index,value) {
             console.log("multiple:",value.split('>')[2].split('<')[0]);
             // send to change
             self.change(value); // substitute value by whatever you want to pass
         });             
      } else {
         console.log("single:",e.val.split('>')[2].split('<')[0]);  
         // send to change
         self.change(value); // substitute value by whatever you want to pass
      }
    });
  },

  willDestroyElement : function() {
    this.$("#select1").select2('destroy');
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this._actions['change'].apply(this, value);
```

Comment: This may or may not solve the problem, but there's nothing here to indicate whay it solves the problem, or where to apply it.

Comment: You better not use private properties/methods as they are subject to change with no guarantee. Use `Component.send()` instead please.